# moveToElement and scrollToView function not working in Chrome browser

Tags: selenium, action

I am trying to move the cursor to specified webelement using the below function using selenium in chrome browser, but it is not working.

Could you please help me to fix it. I am facing same issue for `scrollIntoView` function, too.

Scroll to webelement:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```

Scroll to view:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", btnCheckout);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code :-

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", btnCheckout);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  Ankur,after passing the argument true it is working fine